# A very loud sound shut down my internal MacBook Pro microphone

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, microphone

I have a problem with my internal MacBook Pro microphone.

When there is a very **loud sound** (like sneezing), my **microphone shuts down**. And I am forced to **restart** my computer in order for it to work again.

I searched in the parameters and when the microphone is shut down, OS X doesn’t detect any sound.

**Before the loud sound :**
(with ambient noise)
[image: System Preferences Microphone panel showing sound being picked up]

**After the loud sound :**
(with ambient noise)

[image: System Preferences Microphone panel showing no sound being picked up]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that, maybe due to 'loud' being a subjective measure. Have you tried [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but this don't solved my problem. Yesterday i made update my os (10.11.3) and after this, the speaker and the microphone did not work anymore at all. I contacted the assistance apple and the counselor asked me to do multiple thing like resetting the NVRAM and finally he asked me to reinstall OS X. it seem to work now but I will confirm that in few days.

Comment: I have exactly this problem "microphone gets disabled after loud sound". @MatthieuGrimber, can you confirm if OS X reinstall did help you?